# i want a validation in my Django model that question field would not accept an integer i try but it's not working..How can i do that?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-validation, model-validation

Here this is my Code
#models.py
from django.db import models

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200, null= True)
    option1 = models.CharField(max_length= 200, null= True)
    option2 = models.CharField(max_length= 200, null= True)
    option3 = models.CharField(max_length= 200, null= True)
    option4 = models.CharField(max_length= 200, null= True)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import QuestionForm
from django.views import View
from django.urls import reverse

class AddQuestion(View):

```
def post(self, request):
    forms = QuestionForm(request.POST)
    if forms.is_valid():
        forms.save()
        print("i was in If ")
        return redirect(reverse('home'))
    else:
        print("i was in else ")
        context = {'forms': forms}
        return render(request, 'file/addQuestion.html', context)
    
def get(self, request):
    forms = QuestionForm()
    context = {'forms': forms}
    return render(request,'file/addQuestion.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if request.POST.get('question') is a number with .isdigit()

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: bruh its not working

Comment: Please show code and error messages

Comment: now its working bruh  thank you